# Cannot access "Parse.setApplicationId()"

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to make an app with swift/Obj-c (Bridging Header) with parse.com

So here's my question:
I saw on many sites that you can use `Parse.setApplicationId("appid","clientid")`

When I try this code it says `Use of unresolved Identifier 'Parse'`

I imported the framework and set the bridging header in the properties.
I also imported the frameworks which are required like it's written on parse.com

All other Classes/Objects from parse can be used by swift in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was because of a bug in xcode... (I think the compiler failed)

After I restarted Xcode the error was gone.